# Add matrix to a dataframe using rpy2

Tags: rpy2

I need to use a Dirichlet regression in `Python` and the only implementation I found was available in `R`. Hence, I would like to convert this `R` code into `rpy2` representation.

```r
library(DirichletReg)
data(ArcticLake)

ArcticLake$Y <- DR_data(ArcticLake[, 1:3])
DirichReg(Y ~ depth, data=ArcticLake)
```

`DR_data` function returns a matrix with attributes. I am not really sure of its internal representation in `R` but `str` makes it look like a single item in a list and `print` makes it look like an extra set of 3 columns.

Due to this particularity, I haven't been able to convert the above code to `rpy2`. Running `DR_data` function itself works just fine.

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
dirichlet_reg = importr("DirichletReg")
arctic_lake = data(dirichlet_reg).fetch("ArcticLake")["ArcticLake"]

dr_arctic = dirichlet_reg.DR_data(pandas2ri.ri2py(arctic_lake).iloc[:, 0:3])
```

Assigning the output for a final fit, however, is where I am struggling. I tried this but the final structure is wrong.

```py
arctic_lake.do_slot_assign("Y", dr_arctic)  # arctic_lake$Y <- dr_arctic

fmla = Formula("Y ~ depth")
dirichlet_reg.DirichReg(fmla, data=arctic_lake)
```

How could I properly assign a matrix to a dataframe using `rpy2` the same way `R` does it?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing two differences between the R and Python port.

**Adding the column with the dependent variable 'y':**

I think that `.do_slot_assign()` does not do what you think it does:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
>>> dataf = DataFrame({'x': 1})                                                    
>>> print(dataf)                                                                   
  x
1 1
>>> dataf.do_slot_assign('y', 2)                                                   
print(dataf)                                                                   
  x
1 1
>>> dataf2 = dataf.cbind(z=3)                                                    
>>> print(dataf2)                                                                  
  x z
1 1 3
```

**Extracting columns from the R data frame:**

This one probably not root of the issue, but would spare you the trouble of converting a complete R data frame to pandas just for the sake of taking few columns out of it.

In R you have:

```
ArcticLake$Y <- DR_data(ArcticLake[, 1:3])
```

In Python you have:

```
dr_arctic = dirichlet_reg.DR_data(pandas2ri.ri2py(arctic_lake).iloc[:, 0:3])
```

Python/`rpy2` closer to the R original would have been (see here for details about `.rx()` - https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/vector.html#extracting-r-style):

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector
dr_arctic = dirichlet_reg.DR_data(
    arctic_lake.rx(True, IntVector(range(1, 3+1)))
)
```

Comment: Fair point about the column indexing. As for slots, it looks like a kind of `cbind` but not really since `dr_arctic` is more or less a matrix with attributes but still can't be coerced to a dataframe since it does not inherit `matrix` class. Even back in `R`, `cbind(ArcticLake, Y=dr_arctic)` does not work. It looks to me that `ArcticLake$Y` is held by a single column but somehow understood as and operated on as multiple columns. In the end, I was unable to figure this one out and had to drop it.